# Comparar uma string especifica em um campo em python

Tags: python-3.x

A proposta do código é tentar encontrar a string 'WCDMA FDD Band I' na coluna device_2['Band']. Caso positivo, ele deve marcar 'SIM' no campo device_2['WCDMA FDD Band I'] e caso contrário, ele deve marcar 'NAO' no campo device_2['WCDMA FDD Band I'].

O problema é que ele consegue confirmar se encontrou ou não a string, porém, está marcando todas as linhas do campo device_2['WCDMA FDD Band I'] como 'NAO'.

Segue código:

```
# importando bibliotecas

import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Criando coluna de strings

Band = [['GSM 1800,GSM 1900,GSM 900,GSM850 (GSM800),WCDMA FDD Band I,WCDMA FDD Band II,WCDMA FDD Band V,WCDMA FDD Band VIII'],
                ['GSM 1800,GSM 1900,GSM 900'], ['GSM 1800,GSM 1900,GSM 900,GSM850 (GSM800),HSDPA,WCDMA FDD Band I,WCDMA FDD Band VIII'],
                ['GSM 1800,GSM 1900,GSM 900,GSM850 (GSM800)']]

# Criando data frame com a coluna acima

device_2 = pd.DataFrame(Band, columns=['Band'])

# Adicionando a coluna flag para marcar presença da string WCDMA FDD BAND I

device_2['WCDMA FDD Band I'] = ''

# Percorrendo as linhas do data frame para verificação da string

for index, row in device_2.iterrows():    
    if 'WCDMA FDD Band I' in row['Band']:                    
        **device_2['WCDMA FDD Band I'] = 'SIM'**
        print('Encontrou')
    else:                 
        **device_2['WCDMA FDD Band I'] = 'NAO'**
        print('Nao encontrou')
```

O problema foi resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
# importando bibliotecas

import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Criando coluna de strings

Band = [['GSM 1800,GSM 1900,GSM 900,GSM850 (GSM800),WCDMA FDD Band I,WCDMA FDD Band II,WCDMA FDD Band V,WCDMA FDD Band VIII'],
                ['GSM 1800,GSM 1900,GSM 900'], ['GSM 1800,GSM 1900,GSM 900,GSM850 (GSM800),HSDPA,WCDMA FDD Band I,WCDMA FDD Band VIII'],
                ['GSM 1800,GSM 1900,GSM 900,GSM850 (GSM800)']]

# Criando data frame com a coluna acima

device_2 = pd.DataFrame(Band, columns=['Band'])

# Adicionando a coluna flag para marcar presença da string WCDMA FDD BAND I

device_2['WCDMA FDD Band I'] = ''

# Percorrendo as linhas do data frame para verificação da string

for index, row in device_2.iterrows():    
    if 'WCDMA FDD Band I' in row['Band']:                    
        **row['WCDMA FDD Band I'] = 'SIM'**
        print('Encontrou')
    else:                 
        **row['WCDMA FDD Band I'] = 'NAO'**
        print('Nao encontrou')
```

Quando era passado a coluna (device_2['WCDMA FDD Band I']) para receber SIM ou NÃO, o código entendia que era para setar um único valor na coluna inteira, independente da verificação. Portanto, passei o parâmetro "row" para que o valor fosse setado em cada linha após cada verificação... e deu certo :)

Comment: Qual será o tipo de `row` nesse caso?

Comment: Nesse caso o tipo vai ser <class 'str'>

Comment: `device_2['WCDMA FDD Band I']` será o mesmo para todas linhas? Do jeito que fez ele está atribuindo sempre sim/não ao mesmo objeto.

Comment: device_2['WCDMA FDD Band I'] seria uma coluna fixa para setar a presença da string 'WCDMA FDD Band I' em device['Band'] colocando os valores SIM ou NÃO.

No caso eu teria que criar outro objeto para receber o NÃO?

Comment: Então elabore um [mcve], pois a lógica do código que postou está correta (https://repl.it/@acwoss/LimpingOldlaceVoxels), o problema deve estar em outro lugar.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss coloquei um resumo do código acima... como vc tinha dito, ele encontra a string, porém, na hora de marcar o campo ele assume a condição do ELSE.

Comment: Então, como comentei antes, você está atribuindo o sim/não à mesma variável sempre. Quando sair do `for`, ela terá apenas o valor da última iteração - que neste exemplo é "não".

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss consegui resolver o problema. Eu não estava passando o parametro "row", sem ele o código não estava entendendo que era para setar os valores por linha e colocava o 'NAO' para coluna inteira.

Muito obrigado pela sua atenção.

Comment: Então elabore uma resposta descrevendo como resolveu